# stream_get_contents gets stuck on persistent (KeepAlive) connection

Tags: php

stream_get_contents doesn't seem to handle persistent (KeepAlive) connections correctly. It waits for the connection to timeout before returning. Apache 2.2 has a KeepAliveTimeout of 5 seconds by default. Is there anything I can do about this? (Aside from disabling KeepAlive on the server, or using protocol_version 1.0)

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$stream = fopen('http://google.com', 'r', false, $context);
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
$data = stream_get_contents($stream);
fclose($stream);
```

Thanks.

Comment: same problem with a loop + feof() + fread().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
        'header' => 'Connection: close'
    )
);
```

`Connection: close` tells the server not to use a persistent connection and to drop the TCP connection after the response has been sent.

This is [part of the HTTP/1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10), and as the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.protocol-version) says:

> If [protocol_version] is set to 1.1 it is your responsibility to be 1.1 compliant.